# One modal bootstrap form submited by multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 different price tables placed into different tabs and each of them has 3 different packages. You can see them [here](http://10plus.org/beta/cursuri-elevi/cursuri-engleza-online).

When i click each button unde the package it should open a modal form where i enter client details and then submit the form. When the form is submited i want to know from what package and price table it has been sent from. How can i do that? Thank you.

I hope you understand what i want to do.

Comment: You can use the name attribute of submit buttons and then just get its value from the POST array.

Comment: I want to have only a modal form with only one submite button for all the packages...

Comment: You can add a hidden input and set a different value when each button is clicked.

Comment: And how do i add this hidden input to the form? Because is different for each button. Can you give me an example? Thnak you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/cvp5XNsw1CHrnW9JWyZB?p=preview
```

There are a form with 2 text inputs and a submit button. Below the form you can see 4 buttons: tab1, tab2, tab3 and tab4. Let's say these buttons are your tabs. Each tab button has data-tab attribute with unique value. The data-tab attribute is used to indicate each tab. When you click on one of the tab buttons, the value of submit button is changed. For instance click the tab2 button and submit the form. The data that will be send to server will look like this:

```
input1=1&input2=2&tab=tab2
```

Hope the sample will give you a clue.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!